# Issue with Yahoo Finance API URLs in C# application

Tags: c#, yahoo-finance

I am generating url Strings to return finance data to a windows application and some strings are working while others are not.
For example, I generated this string for Yahoo data and it works perfectly:
    http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=YHOO&a=10&b=13&c=2000&d=10&e=13&f=2000&g=d&ignore=.csv

I then used the same program to generate this string for Google stock:
    http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=10&b=13&c=2008&d=10&e=13&f=2008&g=d&ignore=.csv

The second string string doesn't function.  What am I doing wrong???

Comment: In which context is this a programming question? The URL is not supported by Yahoo. Probably best is to check their API documentation.

Comment: I am generating these from a C# program.  The URL is supported by Yahoo and will generate a CSV file that I am handling in the program.   If you click the first link it will open a CSV for Yahoo stock data on 11/13/2000.

Comment: Again, the generated link doesn't work thanks to Yahoo not accepting it. It is not a C# issue, it is an issue that you (probably) generate a URI which is not supported by Yahoo. I suggest you read their API documentation. If you did and it doesn't work maybe contact their customer support.

Comment: First link works fine for me.  The second one doesn't.  I have read the documentation for the API several times and I cannot see what I am doing wrong.  I was hoping for a second set of eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like their CSV quote data might not go back that far for GOOG. Replacing 2008 with 2014 seems to work without issue. As of now, it looks like 3/27/2014 is the oldest date that they will let you return a CSV for that stock.

Comment: Thank you!  that was the issue.  I will need to pre-fetch the oldest possible date before I validate a starting time.  That solved the issue for all of them!

Answer (score 1):

This is because the ticker symbol `GOOG` now represents Google's Class C stock, which is issued at March 27, 2014.

The original Class A stock is traded under the new symbol `GOOGL`. In order to get its historical data, update the symbol in your link, i.e.

http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOGL&a=10&b=13&c=2008&d=10&e=13&f=2008&g=d&ignore=.csv

Check the details for [Google Stock Split](https://investor.google.com/financial/class-c.html) here.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that, I had no idea.